# get-childitem System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003

I have a directory on a server that contains 2.5 million files.

I need to do something with the files. However, when I try to create an object representing those files, I run into a memory limit. (It's a 32 bit machine.)

```
PS D:\> $files=dir LotsOfFiles
Get-ChildItem : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Is there any way to work around this, like create a class representing a file that stores fewer attributes (I just need name and lastwritedate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try using `dir /b LotsOfFiles` ?

Comment: "dir /b" is a cmd.exe command and does not work in Powershell.

Comment: Wait, I think I get what you mean now. If I do a "cmd /c dir /b" I'd get all the file names and could get the lastwritetime for each file individually. I'll try that.

Comment: The cmd.exe dir can give me the complete paths of every file as strings. That looks better for the moment.